# performSelector in timeintervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following method

```
-(void) showDie: (int) num;{
// do something
}
```

I want to call that method in time intervals of .5 secs. So far I have the following

```
SEL runShowDie;
[runShowDie performSelector:@selector(showDie:) withObject:rand];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:runShowDie userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put repeats:No in this line make it YES

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(showDie:) userInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rand] repeats:YES];
```

Comment: This gives an error" Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC" I forgot to mention that **rand** is the int parameter passed to the showDie method

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showDie:) withObject: rand afterDelay:0.5f];
```

And remove `NSTimer`